# Select top N rows AFTER sorting from Dataview in c#

Tags: c#, dataview

I have a DataTable with 10 rows say one of the columns
numbered 1 to 10 randomly. 
I want to sort them. usually, I do this:

```
DataView Dv = new DataView(dtPost, "", "views desc", DataViewRowState.Unchanged);
repeater.DataSource = Dv;
repeater.DataBind();
```

Now, I just want to bind the top 5 rows in this Dataview. If I try this:

```
DvPopBlogs.Table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5);

OR

DvPopBlogs.Table.AsEnumerable().Take(5); //this usually works if sorting wasnt necessary
```

It works, but the dataView completely forgets about the sorting and just selects 5 rows from top.

I have tried it with all DataViewRowStates too. How to select top 5 rows after sorting?

I seem to run out of ideas!
please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the DataView, but then asking for the `Table` it is bound to - the table itself isn't sorted, the `DataView` provides a sorted "view" of the table.

So try (warning drycode!)

```
DvPopBlogs.DataViewRows.Take(5)
```

To get the first 5 (in sort order) DataViewRows.  If you want the `DataRows`:

```
DvPopBlogs.DataViewRows.Take(5).Select(dvr => dvr.Row)
```

It's quite possible the enumerator from DataView is the DataViewRows collection, so you may be able to just use `DvPopBlogs.Take(5)....` if you wish.

Comment: yea, I found this out when I was trying to debug, dataview seemed to have sorted order but as soon as I added Table, the sort order was lost, now I understand table is the original data. thanks. But, DvPopBlogs is a DataView and it neither has .Take() or .DataViewRows() methods!

Comment: Try either dvPopBlogs.AsEnumerable().Take, or in the worst case dvPopBlogs.ToTable()  The latter will create a new DataTable from the contents of the view.

Comment: Hi, sorry, if I use the .ToTable() method repeater is complaining (on bind) that certain column doesnt exists. Debugging shows that it does exist, may be I am doing something wrong and I am sure you cant find out without the complete code. What do you suggest that I do now? Thanks, and sorry for asking too many questions!

Comment: thanks, I actually figured out that this works, I had a small error in my code and  I was barking up at the wrong tree from five days! I'm an idiot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are casting already to a generic list, why not cast the dataview instead of the datatable?

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> sortedRows = DvPopBlogs.Cast<DataRowView>().Take(5).Select(r => r.Row);
```

Comment: Hi, its still throwing the same error, that one of the column doesn't exist! I have tried to debug it and I can clearly see the column, however, on databind it does throw this error!