# C# - Sorting a datatable by a date column and only binding top 10 records to grid

Tags: c#, linq, soap, datatable, grid

I bind a datatable that contains data from a SOAP call. Unfortunately, the call returns all records for whatever entity i'm fetching and there's no way at the moment of specifying number of records to return or any other argument.

How could I most efficiently sort this datatable by a date column and bind it to a grid while only showing the top 10 records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DataView` so that you can sort and take only the top 10 records.

basically instead of binding the grid to the `DataTable` you filter/sort your `DataView` and bind the grid to the `DataView`.

see this question and answers for details, it looks very similar: [Select top N rows AFTER sorting from Dataview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830913/select-top-n-rows-after-sorting-from-dataview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks Davide! Not quite what I was looking for, but you did set me on the right path to find a solution. I ended up doing something like this:

 Grid.DataSource = dataTableResult.Select("", "Created_Timestamp asc").Take(10);

It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work out for you?

```
var newlist = (from f in list orderby by f.date select f).Take(10).ToList();
```

To help out more, what form does the return take?  A list, an array, etc.